# Compiling RInside program with g++ on Linux

Tags: linux, r, g++, rcpp, rinside

**I have installed R through RPM (with Yast).**

```
anisha@linux-y3pi:~> locate RInside.so
/usr/lib64/R/library/RInside/lib/libRInside.so
/usr/lib64/R/library/RInside/libs/RInside.so

anisha@linux-y3pi:~> locate Rcpp.so
/usr/lib64/R/library/Rcpp/lib/libRcpp.so
/usr/lib64/R/library/Rcpp/libs/Rcpp.so
```

---

The file (`rinsidetest.cpp`) that I wish to compile contains:

```
#include <RInside.h>
#include <Rcpp.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    RInside R (argc, argv);
    return 0;
}
```

---

Here's how I compile it:

```
anisha@linux-y3pi:~> g++ rinsidetest.cpp -I /usr/lib64/R/library/RInside/include/ -I /usr/lib64/R/library/Rcpp/include/ -I /usr/lib64/R/include/ -L /usr/lib64/R/library/RInside/libs/ -L /usr/lib64/R/library/Rcpp/libs/ 

/tmp/ccUfdjgZ.o: In function `main':  
rinsidetest.cpp:(.text+0xb7): undefined reference to `RInside::RInside(int, char const* const*, bool)'  
rinsidetest.cpp:(.text+0xc8): undefined reference to `RInside::~RInside()'  
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

---

R information:

```
> sessionInfo() 
R version 2.15.1 (2012-06-22)
Platform: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=C                 LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tcltk_2.15.1 tools_2.15.1
>
```

`RInside` version: `0.2.6`
`Rcpp` version: `0.9.13`

**Is there a workaround for this problem, or I "have to" remove the rpm installation and start everything by compiling from source?**

EDIT

```
anisha@linux-y3pi:~/Desktop/abc> g++ rinsidetest.cpp -I /usr/lib64/R/library/RInside/include/ -I /usr/lib64/R/library/Rcpp/include/ -I /usr/lib64/R/include/ -L /usr/lib64/R/library/RInside/lib/ -L /usr/lib64/R/library/Rcpp/lib/ -lRInside

anisha@linux-y3pi:~/Desktop/abc> ls  
a.out  rinsidetest.cpp

anisha@linux-y3pi:~/Desktop/abc> ./a.out   
./a.out: error while loading shared libraries: libRInside.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the following to the end of your g++ build

```
 -lRInside -lRcpp
```

so that you have

```
g++ rinsidetest.cpp -I /usr/lib64/R/library/RInside/include/ -I /usr/lib64/R/library/Rcpp/include/ -I /usr/lib64/R/include/ -L /usr/lib64/R/library/RInside/libs/ -L /usr/lib64/R/library/Rcpp/libs/ -lRInside -lRcpp
```

As it stands it doesnt appear that you are linking to the library you need. When you have a library named `libXYZ` you need to link to it using g++ with `-lXYZ` which it appears you have not done. This may fix the problem

Comment: thanks, this did help someway. I have added the new output in the question. I am now getting an error while running `a.out`. Please tell me what's the point I am still missing?

Comment: this is a different problem. The binary has successfully built but it appears that linux is unable to load the .so. It may be a path issue that you need to add. I would post a NEW question for this problem but add the c++ tag instead of the r tag as the c++ community is larger. I am not sure how you tell linux where to look for .so loading of files. Your compilation has worked however but this is a runtime problem. As a temporary fix you could try copying your libs to /usr/lib/ directory just as a TEMPORARY solution to see if you can then run as the exe should pick up from this directory

Comment: @AnishaKaul or even copy to the local directory that your binary is in

Comment: @AnishaKaul You may be better trying a question on a linux forum to ask how to get the .so loading mechanism pick up your directories.

Comment: You can either set the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable to the directory containing the shared library (this is often used for testing, or when you do not have root access), or you can add it to `/etc/ld.so.conf` and run `ldconfig`.

Comment: The package provides an easier way, see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you drop your new test file

```
rinsidetest.cpp
```

into a directory containing the prepared Makefile -- as eg `examples/standard/`, then you only need to say

```
make
```

and the correct executable will be built.  It takes care of the run-time linking issue by embedding the directory.

The idea is for users to take the provided Makefile, and adapt/copy as needed.

Comment: You should work from that Makefile and adapt is as needed in case you require third-party libraries etc.  You can copy the Makefile to any other directory as you see fit.

Comment: yes, thanks. and I've just compiled RgoogleMaps program in RInside. That worked very fine. Thanks.

Comment: I think you did not "compile" RgoogleMaps. You wrote a program containing a call to R functions to load RgoogleMaps. That is different.

Comment: I said `I've just compiled ***RgoogleMaps program***` which is same as what you are saying. :) Or probably some English problems on my part.