# Fatal error for <RInside.h>

Tags: c++, r, rcpp, rinside

I am running this example, through terminal. But got `fatal error: RInside.h: No such file or directory` error for the the line, `#include<RInside.h>`.
Its a interface to R from c++. I have **RInside** package in R.
my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<RInside.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int a=12;
    cout<<a<<endl;
    return 0;  
}
```

Same error occurred for `#include<Rcpp.h>` header.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector callFunction(NumericVector x, Function f) {
    NumericVector res = f(x);
    return res;
}
```

Package RInside version 0.2.14

Package Rcpp version 0.12.17

Comment: Locate those headers on your filesystem and ensure they are visible by the compiler (they are in the list of paths that the compiler checks for headers). Also, what OS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `GNUmakefile` shipped with `RInside` in the `examples` folder includes things like:

```
## comment this out if you need a different version of R, 
## and set set R_HOME accordingly as an environment variable
R_HOME :=       $(shell R RHOME)

[...]
## include headers and libraries for R 
RCPPFLAGS :=        $(shell $(R_HOME)/bin/R CMD config --cppflags)
RLDFLAGS :=         $(shell $(R_HOME)/bin/R CMD config --ldflags)
RBLAS :=        $(shell $(R_HOME)/bin/R CMD config BLAS_LIBS)
RLAPACK :=      $(shell $(R_HOME)/bin/R CMD config LAPACK_LIBS)

## if you need to set an rpath to R itself, also uncomment
#RRPATH :=      -Wl,-rpath,$(R_HOME)/lib

## include headers and libraries for Rcpp interface classes
## note that RCPPLIBS will be empty with Rcpp (>= 0.11.0) and can be omitted
RCPPINCL :=         $(shell echo 'Rcpp:::CxxFlags()' | $(R_HOME)/bin/R --vanilla --slave)
RCPPLIBS :=         $(shell echo 'Rcpp:::LdFlags()'  | $(R_HOME)/bin/R --vanilla --slave)


## include headers and libraries for RInside embedding classes
RINSIDEINCL :=      $(shell echo 'RInside:::CxxFlags()' | $(R_HOME)/bin/R --vanilla --slave)
RINSIDELIBS :=      $(shell echo 'RInside:::LdFlags()'  | $(R_HOME)/bin/R --vanilla --slave)

## compiler etc settings used in default make rules
CXX :=          $(shell $(R_HOME)/bin/R CMD config CXX)
CPPFLAGS :=         -Wall $(shell $(R_HOME)/bin/R CMD config CPPFLAGS)
CXXFLAGS :=         $(RCPPFLAGS) $(RCPPINCL) $(RINSIDEINCL) $(shell $(R_HOME)/bin/R CMD config CXXFLAGS)
LDLIBS :=       $(RLDFLAGS) $(RRPATH) $(RBLAS) $(RLAPACK) $(RCPPLIBS) $(RINSIDELIBS)
```

If you use GNU make, you can probably use this literally. Otherwise you will have to adapt it for your build environment. Please look at the provided examples for more details.

Comment: I have tried this. https://stackoverflow.com/a/21225890/9113303 through R studio and while running i just got *Rcpp::sourceCpp('Desktop/cuda_pgm_cpp/mySum.cpp')* as output but how to get the return values. I am passing 2 parameters through the function.

Comment: @Aswathy What is the relation to this question about `RInside`? What are you trying to do explicitly?

Comment: :Trying to call a R function from c++ (with passing arguments), For that Rcpp and RInside are the useful packages.

Comment: @Aswathy Did you look through the examples that come with `RInside`? If those do not provide enough details, then you should provide a [mcve] for what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the path of header file when compiling RInside with g++. There is a parameters list of g++ on Mac OS X (10.14.2 Mojave) for your reference, hope this help.

```
g++ 
-I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/RInside/include \
-I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/Rcpp/include \
-I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/include \
-L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/lib \
-L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/RInside/lib \
-lR -lRInside -O3 -o test helloworld_rinside.cpp
```

source code of "helloworld_rinside.cpp", http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rinside.html

```
// -*- mode: C++; c-indent-level: 4; c-basic-offset: 4;  tab-width: 8; -*-
//
// Simple example showing how to do the standard 'hello, world' using embedded R
//
// Copyright (C) 2009 Dirk Eddelbuettel
// Copyright (C) 2010 Dirk Eddelbuettel and Romain Francois
//
// GPL'ed

#include <RInside.h> // for the embedded R via RInside

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  RInside R(argc, argv); // create an embedded R instance

  R["txt"] = "Hello, world!\n"; // assign a char* (string) to 'txt'

  R.parseEvalQ("cat(txt)"); // eval the init string, ignoring any returns

  exit(0);
}
```